# Excessive memory usage

Tags: c#, memory-management, garbage-collection, asp.net-core-6.0

I have a ASP.NET Core 6 application which from time to time consumes a WCF service. The basic implementation looks like this:

```
builder.Services.AddSingleton<StorageCostDataService>();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<PeriodicDataSnapshotService>();
builder.Services.AddHostedService<PeriodicDataSnapshotService>(provider => 
provider.GetRequiredService<PeriodicDataSnapshotService>());
```

`StorageCostDataService` is a WCF client which connects to a server and retrieves some data. The `PeriodicDataSnapshotService` is basically defined as

```
public class PeriodicDataSnapshotService : BackgroundService
{
    private PeriodicTimer? _periodicTimer;

    private readonly StorageCostDataService _storageCostDataService;

    public PeriodicDataSnapshotService(StorageCostDataService storageCostDataService)
    {
        _storageCostDataService = storageCostDataService;
    }

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        _periodicTimer = new PeriodicTimer(_period);

        while (await _periodicTimer.WaitForNextTickAsync(stoppingToken))
        {
            try
            {
                var storageStateViewerContext = new StorageStateViewerContext();

                var storageCostOverviewData = _storageCostDataService.GetStorageCostOverviewData(2000);

                var storageCostOverviewRemainingValueHistoryData = _storageCostDataService.GetStorageCostOverviewRemainingValueData(2000);

                storageStateViewerContext.StorageOverviewHistories.Add(storageOverviewHistory);
                storageStateViewerContext.SaveChanges();

                storageCostOverviewData = null;
                storageCostOverviewRemainingValueHistoryData = null;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.LogError(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

It retrieves data from the WCF Service `storageCostDataService`, does some calculations and stores the manipulated data into a database (`storageStateViewerContext` is an EF `DbContext`).

During debugging I was able to observe excessive memory usage. The application starts off at about 60 MB until the service is consumed which adds another 200 MB. This would be fine, but as soon as the timer restarts, it adds another 200 MB, then again and again.

There is some point in time when the garbage collector hits and it will free some memory (so about from 3 GB down to 2 GB or so). Then it piles up until it hits those 3 GB again, Garbage Collector kicks in, down to 2 GB. Each time the service is consumed, it adds an additional 200 MB. It's not always 3 GB, sometimes it's around 1.2 GB, sometimes it's 2 GB. It seems there is some limit where the garbage collector actually does it's work but still keeps some part.

From what I understand, the GC should collect everything that's not in use anymore. If I perform a memory snapshot I can see that the memory footprint of the application without "dead objects" is around 100-200 MB which is perfectly fine. If I check the checkbox to show the dead objects, it adds much more (hundreds of MBs). If I view the object, I can see that those all come from the `storageCostDataService`.

Apparently that data is stored and not garbage collected. Does anybody know the reason for this?

I understand that I cannot really force the GC to collect everything but 100s of MBs are just lying around and using up memory. I hesitate to put that into production. Don't get me wrong, it works and does what it's supposed to do but ...

This is the implementation of the WCF client:

```
public Dictionary<string, List<ErpBatchCostOverviewItem>> GetStorageCostOverviewData(int limit)
{
    using (var svc = new ErpInterfaceWebserviceClient())
    {
        var b = svc.Endpoint.Binding as BasicHttpBinding;

        if (b == null)
        {
            throw new Exception("Couldn't create service endpoint");
        }

        b.MaxReceivedMessageSize = int.MaxValue;
        b.BypassProxyOnLocal = true;
        b.UseDefaultWebProxy = false;

        var endpoint = svc.Endpoint;
        endpoint.Address = new EndpointAddress("http://svr-el-sql.work.local:1035/ErpInterface");

        svc.OpenAsync().Wait();

        var serverData = svc.GetErpBatchCostOverview();

        svc.Close();

        var erpBatchCostOverviewItems = serverData
                .Where(d => d.GroupId != 71)
                .GroupBy(d => d.Ident)
                .OrderByDescending(d => d.Sum(e => e.Price * e.Amount))
                .Take(limit)
                .ToDictionary(d => d.Key, d => d.ToList())
            ;

        return erpBatchCostOverviewItems;
    }
}
```

As @dbc has pointed out, I have since wrapped the DbContext in a using statement and made the PeriodicTimer a local field but the memory behaviour has not really changed.

I took a picture from the Diagnostic Tools in Visual Studio

[image: Diagnostic Tools]

The data is collected each time the memory usage goes up a little. The garbage collector kicks in three times. The first time at around 400MB, the second at around 1.5GB and the third at around 2.2 (from where it will drop down to 1.5GB).

This is from the memory usage snapshot:

[image: No dead objects]

[image: with dead objects]

Observe the difference between the list without dead objects and the list which includes those. Apparently a lot of items come from the ErpInterfaceService which is the WCF client and its data.

Comment: [`PeriodicTimer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.periodictimer?view=net-8.0) is disposable but you are not disposing of it.  Fix that and see if the problem goes away.

Comment: If `StorageStateViewerContext` is a [`DbContext`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.dbcontext) then it is disposable as well.  Make sure that you dispose of all instances of any types that implement `IDisposable` (other than `HttpClient`) immediately after you are done with.

Comment: @dbc  Shouldn't PeriodicTimer have a lifetime for the whole duration as long the the service exists? The timer is supposed to trigger every 10 minutes or so

Comment: The general pattern I follow with disposables is (without thinking too much beforehand) to declare them in the smallest possible scope and dispose of them when exiting the scope.  Generally that gives a good result.    In your case it seems like `_periodicTimer` is not used outside `ExecuteAsync()` so I would change it from a field to a local variable in `ExecuteAsync()` and bracket it in a `using` statement.  And of course dispose of all `DbContext` instances and other disposables as well (instead of nulling them out).  Having ensured all disposables are disposed as soon as possible, re-test.

Comment: @dbc I added some more information ...

Comment: In your testing, are you using Normal (Workstation) or Concurrent (Server) Garbage Collection strategies?  See e.g. [What is server garbage collection in ASP.NET Core?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44134508) and [Workstation and server garbage collection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/workstation-server-gc) vs [When does garbage collection get triggered in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28461652).

Comment: Also, is there any chance you are allocating blocks of memory larger than 85,000 bytes (e.g. strings longer than 42500 characters) that are going on the [large object heap](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/large-object-heap)?  If so you may be fragmenting memory.

Comment: @dbc It took me a while to digest this information and I had to read up a lot on GC. I am more and more thinking that the issue lies with Server GC vs. Workstation GC. It appears that the Server GC will hog memory until it determines it's not needed anymore. I have run the very same application in Workstation GC mode and the memory usage stays at around 200MB (sometimes a bit more, sometimes a bit less). I can see the GC triggering far more often and it makes GC Gen 1 and Gen 2 tasks whereas in Server GC mode I can only see Gen 2 GC.

Comment: I do not expect a high load situation since this is a service which is used exlusively on an internal network so I tend to enable Workstation GC because there are other processes running on that machine as well .. Still thinking if I should try to keep Server GC enabled and observe the memory usage during runtime.

Comment: Please can you add a using block around the `var storageStateViewerContext = new StorageStateViewerContext();` and report back?

Comment: See the response from @dbc above. Did that but it didn't change a thing.

Comment: @TomL. - sorry that didn't help.  You might want to [edit] your question to add in the missing `using` statements so that future readers will know that wasn't the problem.  Good luck!